# How to pretty print Hibernate query results?

Tags: java, hibernate

When Hibernate returns a list of existing entities it's easy. But when using projections, the type of the list is not printable.

```
    List list = session
            .createCriteria(Product.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("name"))
                .add(Projections.property("price"))
            )
            .list();
    System.out.println(list);
```

Result:

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@12365c88, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6105f8a3, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2237bada, [Ljava.lang.Object;@77e2a6e2, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5710768a, [Ljava.lang.Object;@199e4c2b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@6e0d4a8, [Ljava.lang.Object;@64d7b720, [Ljava.lang.Object;@30272916, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5bb3d42d]
```

Is there any API for printing Hibernate's results?

Comment: It's a `List<Object[]>`. You can loop and use Arrays.toString() on each element of the list.

Comment: I've found that you all the queries sent to the database can be check if you set TRACE log level for your JDBC library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.Arrays` for converting to String. 
Ex: 
`Arrays.toString(list)`